# Can Crunchyroll's translations (subtitles, dubs, manga) be considered official translations?

Tags: anime-production, crunchyroll

Crunchyroll licences anime for simultaneous streaming (simultaneous with the Japanese TV airing, in some cases), so it should have early access to the material to be translated.

I won't touch on how they do it or who does it; what I am interested in knowing is:

Is the translation shown in CR to be taken as the official translation?

Comment: They're licensed to do so, so therefore that means they're official.

Comment: Whether they're good or not is another matter.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ ok. I am going with this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598

Answer (score 4):

Since Crunchyroll has a license from the copyright owner, the content (including cuts / edited video, subtitles, translations, overlay text, dubbing) available is considered official.

Even though Crunchyroll does the translation, the translation is owned by the  anime studio. Also, sometimes the studio chooses how some terms are translated.